# How to do a volume rendering of 3D dataset in Mayavi?

Tags: python, mayavi

I have a dataset which is generally 3D image stack. Now I want to display it as a volumetric image by using Mayavi. However, since my spacing of my dataset is not equally spaced in three axis. What should I do to ensure the right spacing. I am trying a simple example with the following codes. but the result still gives me a flat 3D sphere. I am wondering what modify this code.

```
import os
import time
import matplotlib 
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from mayavi import mlab
import mayavi as myv 
from tvtk.pyface import light_manager
from traits.api import HasPrivateTraits, HasTraits, Any, Int, \
    Property, Instance, Event, Range, Bool, Trait, Str
from tvtk.util import ctf

class MplColorHelper:
    def __init__(self, cmap_name, start_val, stop_val):
        self.cmap_name = cmap_name
        self.cmap = plt.get_cmap(cmap_name)
        self.norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=start_val, vmax=stop_val)
        self.scalarMap = cm.ScalarMappable(norm=self.norm, cmap=self.cmap)
        print("color clim is {}".format(self.scalarMap.get_clim()))
    def get_rgb(self, val,alpha):
        return self.scalarMap.to_rgba(val,alpha=alpha,bytes=True)


def ChangeVolColormap(vol,cmapName, vmin, vmax, alpha):
    """
    Change colormap of mlab volume plot 
    input: 
    : vol: mlab.pipeline.volume return object 
    : cmapName: name, default is 'jet' 
    : vmin, vmax, alpha: parameters for cmap  
    """    
    cmapD = MplColorHelper(cmapName,start_val=vmin,stop_val=vmax)
    from tvtk.util.ctf import ColorTransferFunction
    ctf0 = ColorTransferFunction()
    #print(ctf0.__dict__)
    #ctf0.range = (0,255)
    colorValue = np.linspace(vmin,vmax,1024) #np.arange(vmin,vmax,step=0.1,dtype=np.float)
    print("Num of colormap values is {}".format(np.size(colorValue)))
    for i in range(np.size(colorValue)):     
        cT = cmapD.get_rgb(colorValue[i],alpha)
        ctf0.add_rgb_point(colorValue[i],cT[0]/255, cT[1]/255, cT[2]/255)  # r, g, and b are float between 0 and 1
    ctf0.nan_color = (0.0,0.0,0.0)
    ctf0.nan_opacity = 1.0 
    above_cT = cmapD.get_rgb(colorValue[-1],alpha)
    below_cT = cmapD.get_rgb(colorValue[0],alpha)
    ctf0.use_above_range_color = False 
    ctf0.use_below_range_color = False
    ctf0.above_range_color = (above_cT[0]/255,above_cT[1]/255,above_cT[2]/255)
    ctf0.below_range_color = (below_cT[0]/255,below_cT[1]/255,below_cT[2]/255)

    # save the color transfer function of the current volume
    c = ctf.save_ctfs(vol._volume_property)
    # change the alpha channel as needed
    c['alpha'][1][1] = alpha 
    # load the new color transfer function
    ctf.load_ctfs(c, vol._volume_property)
    vol._volume_property.set_color(ctf0)
    vol._ctf = ctf0
    vol.update_ctf = True
    
    return vol 

def volumeRender(z,x,y,cellVol,rootPath=''):
    f = mlab.figure(bgcolor=(0,0,0),size=(1024,1024))    
    cellVol[cellVol==0] = np.nan 
    
    vmax = np.nanpercentile(cellVol,90)
    vmin = np.nanpercentile(cellVol,10)

    cellVolsrc = myv.tools.pipeline.scalar_field(x,y,z,cellVol) 
    cellVolsrc.spacing = [1.0,1.0,1.0]#[0.3/0.0726,0.3/0.0726,1.0]
   
    vol = mlab.pipeline.volume(cellVolsrc,figure=f)
    vol = ChangeVolColormap(vol,cmapName="Reds",vmin=vmin,vmax=vmax,alpha=1.0)
    vol.update_pipeline()
    cam = f.scene.camera
    cam.zoom(1.0)
   
    ax = mlab.axes(nb_labels=20,ranges=[np.amin(x),np.amax(x),np.amin(y),np.amax(y),np.amin(z),np.amax(z)])
    ax.axes.label_format = "%.2f"
    ax.label_text_property.font_size = 1
    ax.axes.x_label = "X"
    ax.axes.y_label = "Y"
    ax.axes.z_label = "Z"
    if animateDo:
        ax.axes.visibility = 0
    else:
        ax.axes.visibility = 1
    oax = mlab.orientation_axes(xlabel="x",ylabel="y",zlabel="z") 
    oax._text_property.use_tight_bounding_box = True 
    oax.update_pipeline()
    

    mlab.show() 


    return 1 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    x = np.arange(0,100,step=0.5) 
    y = np.arange(0,100,step=0.5) 
    z = np.arange(0,50,step=2) 
    x = x - np.mean(x) 
    y = y - np.mean(y) 
    z = z - np.mean(z) 

    Z,X,Y = np.meshgrid(z,x,y)
    vol = np.asarray((X**2 + Y**2 + Z**2)<100,dtype=np.float16)*np.random.rand(np.shape(Z)[0],np.shape(Z)[1],np.shape(Z)[2]) * 255
    volumeRender(Z,X,Y,vol)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it for medical image volume rendering?

I was working in medical image analysis during my PhD, and wrote a [Python script basing on Mayavi](https://github.com/goballooning/show).
There is a function `saveImageVolum3d4mayavi.m` for writing data into `.mat` file from Matlab, and you can specify the spacing and origin as options.